# Subscription payment with PayPal Payments API

Tags: paypal, e-commerce, payment-gateway, payment-processing

How to create a subscription payment (with or without payment right now in addition to subscription) with [PayPal Checkout Server Integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/how-to/server-integration/) and [Payments API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v1/)?

It seems that the "transaction" object type in [Payments API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v1/) has nothing about recurring payments.

I am writing [an open source engine](https://github.com/vporton/django-debits) to receive payments on the Internet. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done with the API documented here:

- https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-plans/v1/
- https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-agreements/v1/